Movie: Romance movie on a plane
I am trying to identify a movie I watched about 3 years ago on TV.
It is about a college professor who has marriage issues and finds love on a plane. Most of the movie is set in a plane and the movie is in English(not sure about the country). The professor(he) meets the woman(who got dumped recently) in the plane and cheers her up in her depressed state. Anyways, the story progresses on and by some misunderstanding they part on bad terms after landing. The later meet up and the story has a happy ending.
Extra points:

The hero plays guitar
The director is a woman (not sure)
I think it was a Nickelodeon production movie (not sure)


Please tell me that at some point one of the characters says "I have had it with this mothering romance on this mothering plane!"

Possibly Overnight from 2012, directed by Valerie Breiman. 
Among the passengers are a college professor (Tom, played by James D'Arcy) and a young woman, who broke up with her boyfriend on Valentine's Day (Jenny, played by Rachel Blanchard).
Trailer: 


(Tom playing the banjo(?) at 00:15 sec)
(Note: Not to be confused with The Overnight (2015))

Thanks for the reply. This was the movie I was looking for.
